# Why is the Google Drive template will no longer be available after 2016?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I'm using constantly with templates at MS Word, and I seek to move away from it to use only with Google Docs as much as I can for ease my workflow.
But I encounter [this help page](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/148833) not long ago, and it raise some questions in me.
Is this feature will no longer be available for me after 2016?
If it wouldn't, how could I keep using templates in Docs?

Comment: It is literally not possible to answer the reason the Google Drive template is no longer available if that reason wasn't shared by Google.

Answer (score 2):

The page you linked answers your question.

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/148833

"The Google Drive template gallery will be taken down in the near future. At that time, https://drive.google.com/templates will no longer work.

***Use the new template galleries in the Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides home screens.***"

For example, https://docs.google.com/document/ - The templates at the top there will remain.

Comment: I see now, I saw that *only* after I changed my UI language to English.
But how can I add a different template after 2016?

Comment: @HashiramaSenju - If its not documented, and its not applicable at this current time, then we cannot answer the question.  In any event, your question about Google Documents, isn't on topic here at Superuser

Comment: @HashiramaSenju - You save a copy of an existing template then you modify it, per the article, you linked to.